# How to write a pseudo Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Using VB.net, C# and SQL Server

I want to write a pseudo for my application.

pseudo code is like coding or flow chart...?

Can any one provide a sample pseudo code for any type of application.

Comment: Why do you need this pseudo code? How can you have these tags for your question?

Comment: What the.......? Do you know what pseudo code is? I hope you don't think it's a feature of .NET or something...

Comment: I guess your real question is "What is pseudocode?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo code is just a way to express the intent of the program without being syntactically correct.

An example could be:

```
print "What is your name"
read input from user
print "Hello " + user input
```

Another example for withdrawing money from an ATM:

```
if the selected account's balance is greater than the requested amount
    reduce balance by requested amount
else
    display error message
end if
```

Answer (score 10):

Here's an algorithm for writing pseudo code:

> write in your own words

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be helpful:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-code

Particularly:

> No standard for pseudocode syntax
>   exists, as a program in pseudocode is
>   not an executable program. Pseudocode
>   resembles, but should not be confused
>   with, skeleton programs including
>   dummy code, which can be compiled
>   without errors. Flowcharts can be
>   thought of as a graphical alternative
>   to pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-code is supposed to be a natural language equivalent of code, for example:

```
while there are items left to process
   process the current item
   remove the item from the collection
```