# Pseudocode for ping application to check the nodes a network

Tags: c#, ping, pseudocode

I'm new to computer programming. I am currently preparing homework assignment. I came across this question.
Write a pseudocode for ping application which can be then be written in C# program to check nodes in a network.

I wanted to know what a pseduocode? Read that it is a decsription on how to write the code. I am bit familar with python code but not much on C#.
Can you guys help?

Comment: What help do you need

Comment: I like to know how a sample pesudocode looks like.. for example for making a normal ping application

Comment: check this:      https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Pseudo-Code-of-Ping-Development_fig3_232619410

Comment: pseudocode is using the right statements but instead of logic writing what the logic will do in your own words so basically use if .. else bu instead of real code describe what needs to be checked and what needs to happen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a pseudo Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931499/how-to-write-a-pseudo-code)

Comment: pseudocode is about writing the basic logic of what the program should do. Without underlying details that wouldn't help to explain the logic, like f.e. declaring variables. There's not really a standard for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Pseudocode is an informal high-level description of the operating principle of a computer program or other algorithm. It uses the structural conventions of a normal programming language but is intended for human reading rather than machine reading ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode))

Some basic examples

eg1.Write a Pseudocode for,
if student mark is 50+ that student pass, else the student has failed

answer

```
 if studentMark is more than equal to 50  
display pass
  else 
display failed
```

as you can see there is no "actual code" but a basic understanding of what the code should do.

extra [Pseudocode Examples](https://www.csharp-console-examples.com/general/pseudocode-examples/)